# Simple outer join between two tables not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a very simple query , and yet I can't get it to work like I want it to.

I have 2 tables, `A` and `B` which are very similar and look like this :

`A` :

```
+------+----------+---------+
| a_id | a_cnt_id | a_value |
+------+----------+---------+
| 1    | 848      | 0.5     |
| 2    | 848      | 3       |
| 3    | 848      | 4       |
| 4    | 848      | 65      |
+------+----------+---------+
```

`B` :

```
+------+----------+---------+
| b_id | b_cnt_id | b_value |
+------+----------+---------+
| 1    | 849      | 36      |
| 2    | 849      | 42      |
| 3    | 849      | 8       |
+------+----------+---------+
```

`B` has more records than `A` for a given set of `{a_cnt_id, b_cnt_id}`.

I would like my query to return this :

```
+------+------+---------+---------+
| a_id | b_id | a_value | b_value |
+------+------+---------+---------+
| 1    | 1    | 0.5     | 36      |
| 2    | 2    | 3       | 42      |
| 3    | 3    | 4       | 8       |
| 4    | NULL | 65      | NULL    |
+----+--------+---------+---------+
```

My (not working) query, because it returns only the first 3 rows :

```
select distinct a.a_id, b.b_id, a.a_value, b.b_value
from b
full join a on b.b_id = a.a_id
where a.a_cnt_id = 849
and b.b_cnt_id = 848;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `WHERE` clause will filter the results to what the where suggests. So if you have `where a.a_cnt_id = 849` it will get only these rows, not the ones with the `null`. Move your filters to the join:

```
select distinct a.a_id, b.b_id, a.a_value, b.b_value
from b
full join a on b.b_id = a.a_id
and a.a_cnt_id = 849
and b.b_cnt_id = 848;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember where I found this but here you go:
[image]

EDIT:
The link of the image belongs to [Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins). Thanks @jyparask

Comment: Here maybe.... http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Move the `cnt_id` checks to the `ON` clause instead to preserve the OUTER JOIN, like so:

```
select distinct a.a_id, b.b_id, a.a_value, b.b_value
from b
full join a on b.b_id = a.a_id
and a.a_cnt_id = 849
and b.b_cnt_id = 848;
```